# Add a checkbox in WPF datagrid header and use it to select/unselect all checkboxes in DataGridCheckBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am new to WPF and would appreciate help on following problem.

In my wpf datagrid I have DataGridCheckBoxColumn as first column and I have bind this column to IsSelected property in ViewModel.

```
<toolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding isSelected}"/>
```

I also want to have a checkbox in header row and which I intend to use to select/unselect all the checkboxes in this column.

Till now I have managed to get a checkbox in header by applying a headerstyle as shown in below  code snip but I am not able to toggle selection for all the checkboxes in column

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <CheckBox x:Name="chkToggleSelection"   VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </CheckBox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Comment: are you using SL or WPF?

Comment: Dmitry I am using WPF for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to handle the `Checkbox.Click` event (if you are using MVVM then set the `CheckBox.Command` or use attached behavior to handle the event) and then set the boolean property of all items bound to the datagrid as true \ false accordingly.

Sadly there is no other alternative that I am aware of!

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgLines" ItemsSource="{Binding OpcUaEndpoints}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     SelectionMode="Extended"  IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Name="ckbSelectedAll" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked" >
                                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked" >
                                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.UncheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Name="cbkSelect" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id }" />-->

                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="500" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="500" Header="Lines" Binding="{Binding Endpoint}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>


        public class OpcUaEndpointsListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
            {
                private static OpcUaEndpointsListViewModel _instance;
                private static readonly object Padlock = new object();
                private ICommand _addCommand;
                //private ICommand _uncheckCommand;
                private ICommand _searchcommand;
                private ICommand _checkedCommand { get; set; }
                private ICommand _unCheckedCommand { get; set; }

                private ObservableCollection<AddOpcUaEndpointsViewModel> _endpoint;
                public string _charNameFromTB;

                public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                public OpcUaEndpointsListViewModel()
                {
                    BindDataGrid();
                }

                public static OpcUaEndpointsListViewModel Instance
                {
                    get
                    {
                        lock (Padlock)
                        {
                            return _instance ?? (_instance = new OpcUaEndpointsListViewModel());
                        }
                    }
                }

                /// <summary>
                ///     //OPC UA Endpoint List
                /// </summary>
                public ObservableCollection<AddOpcUaEndpointsViewModel> OpcUaEndpoints
                {
                    get { return _endpoint; }
                    set
                    {
                        if (OpcUaEndpoints == value)
                        {
                            _endpoint = value;
                            OnPropertyChanged("OpcUaEndpoints");
                        }
                    }
                }

                public string CharNameFromTB
                {
                    get { return _charNameFromTB; }
                    set
                    {
                        _charNameFromTB = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("CharNameFromTB");
                    }
                }

                public ICommand AddCommand
                {
                    get { return _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new WpfApplication1.RelayCommand<object>(p => ExecuteAddCommand())); }
                }

                public ICommand SearchCommand
                {
                    get { return _searchcommand ?? (_searchcommand = new RelayCommand<object>(p => ExecuteSearchCommand())); }
                }


                public ICommand CheckedCommand
                {
                    get { return _checkedCommand ?? (_checkedCommand = new WpfApplication1.RelayCommand<object>(p => ExecuteCheckedCommand())); }
                }
                public ICommand UncheckedCommand
                {
                    get { return _unCheckedCommand ?? (_unCheckedCommand = new WpfApplication1.RelayCommand<object>(p => ExecuteUnCheckedCommand())); }
                }


                private void ExecuteSearchCommand()
                {
                    ///BindDataGridsearch();
                }

                private void ExecuteCheckedCommand()
                {
                    foreach (var item in _endpoint)
                    {
                        item.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }

                private void ExecuteUnCheckedCommand()
                {
                    foreach (var item in _endpoint)
                    {
                        item.IsSelected = false;
                    }
                }

                private void ExecuteAddCommand()
                {
                    ///BindDataGridsearch();
                }

                private void BindDataGrid()
                {
                    _endpoint = new ObservableCollection<AddOpcUaEndpointsViewModel>();
                    _endpoint.Add(new AddOpcUaEndpointsViewModel { Name = "A", Description = "A", Endpoint = 1 });
                    _endpoint.Add(new AddOpcUaEndpointsViewModel { Name = "B", Description = "B", Endpoint = 2 });
                    _endpoint.Add(new AddOpcUaEndpointsViewModel { Name = "C", Description = "C", Endpoint = 3 });
                    _endpoint.Add(new AddOpcUaEndpointsViewModel { Name = "D", Description = "D", Endpoint = 4 });
                    _endpoint.Add(new AddOpcUaEndpointsViewModel { Name = "E", Description = "E", Endpoint = 5 });
                }

                public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
                {
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

public class AddOpcUaEndpointsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }

        private string _description;

        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value; OnPropertyChanged("Description"); }
        }

        private int _endPoint;

        public int Endpoint
        {
            get { return _endPoint; }
            set { _endPoint = value; OnPropertyChanged("Endpoint"); }
        }

        private bool _isSelected;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set { _isSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have given an working example of adding a checkbox to the column header in datagrid and shows how to handle select/unselect all checkbox in the viewmodel.