# Add a SelectAll CheckBox to a wpf datagrid column?

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, wpfdatagrid, selectall

Please if you can help me, I want to add a selectall checkbox to the first column in my wpf datagrid, how can I do it ? Thanks.

```
                       <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                    EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                    Header="Select"
                                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"                                                        
                                    />                               

                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Matricule" Width="100"  Binding="{Binding Matricule}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Nom}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prenom" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Prenom}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Recrutement" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Telephone" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Telephone}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="E-mail" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Compte" Width="80" Binding="{Binding CompteFonct}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Banque\CCP" Width="80" Binding="{Binding CodeBanque}"/>                                

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a checkbox in WPF datagrid header and use it to select/unselect all checkboxes in DataGridCheckBoxColumn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212340/add-a-checkbox-in-wpf-datagrid-header-and-use-it-to-select-unselect-all-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Please use ComboBox Template inside the grid. Check below link for your reference.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF
[Combo box in WPF application with select/deselect all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858217/combo-box-in-wpf-application-with-select-deselect-all)